# Parallel replication is not working on a 5.7 slave from a 5.7 master

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, parallelism

Note: Following are the parameters that we turned ON on the 5.7 replica for parallel replication to happen:

```
slave_preserve_commit_order = 1
slave_parallel_type = LOGICAL_CLOCK
slave_parallel_workers = 10
log_slave_updates = 1
backup retention enabled for 1 day on the slave
```

On the 5.7 master, the following parameters were set:

```
binlog_order_commits = 1
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay = 50
```

We can see from watching the following query that only single threaded replication is happening:

```sql
select * from performance_schema.threads where name="thread/sql/slave_worker";
```

By executing the above query we saw that only one of the slave workers are actually committing to the database and for all the other threads it shows a status of "Waiting for an event from Coordinator"

Would like to know why exactly parallel replication is not working

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can only use as many threads as are actually needed for replication given your database workload. The fact that those threads are visible would imply that parallel execution is in effect. Take a look at what a "SHOW PROCESSLIST" yields. More specifically, look at what the "time" column for the replication threads shows.

Comment: I was previously ignoring the fact that the parallelism that can be achieved by the slave workers depends heavily on the workload. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The parallelism that can be achieved on any 5.7 instance which is a slave to a 5.7 master depends heavily on the workload.

We can however tweak the level of parallelism to a certain degree using the [binlog_group_commit_sync_delay](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_group_commit_sync_delay) variable on the master. Increasing this variable typically increases the number of transactions to be committed in a group(in the binary log of the master), therefore increasing the number of parallel transactions on the slave.

Typically in most cases of oltp transactions, having `binlog_order_commit`=1 on the master and `slave_preserve_commit_order`=1 on the slave is the way to go as commits going out of order can render the slave data becoming inconsistent. 
Note that having for `slave_preser_commit_order` to be enabled, binary logs must be enabled on the slave. Technically this would slow down the slave thus impacting performance however this is a technical restriction of mysql and `slave_preserve_commit_order` has really nothing to do with binary logging. Folks have [reported](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75396) this to mysql and its probably going to be removed in future releases.